# Laravel 4 PHP Not Found

Tags: php, linux, laravel, lampp

I am trying to setup my first laravel project. I am running XAMPP for Linux (LAMPP) and I installed composer in /opt/lampp/bin/php.

1. I then cd /opt/lampp/htdocs
2. I then run: /opt/lampp/bin/php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel new_proj --prefer-dist
3. Everything seems to be going great for the install then I get

   - Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
   - [Runtime Exception]
   - Error Output: sh: 1: php: not found
4. I have PHP 5.4.

I think I understand the error but I don't know Laravel well enough to solve this. I have searched for this and can't seem to find an answer.

Also I can't seem to find a good starting point for trying to install this on XAMPP for Linux (LAMPP). Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that I did not specify

```
/opt/lampp/bin
```

in my Path so it could not find PHP and more specifically it could not find the version of PHP that I was using in LAMPP. So I added

```
Path=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

to my ~/.bashrc file then I was able to successfully install laravel. Next issue that came up after that was setting permissions on the appropriate folders.

**Permissions Problem, See Below:**

1. Set permission for your project folder: 
   `sudo chmod 755 -R laravel_proj_name`
2. Set permission for your project storage folder: 
   `sudo chmod o+w -R laravel_proj_name/app/storage`
3. Refresh Page, Good to Go!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the PHP CLI binary is not in your path. Try adding it to your path or putting a symbolic link into /usr/bin or some other appropriate place.